# Service method name is not valid. from Hosted server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I got this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: ManageUser Web Service method name
>   is not valid.    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type,
>   HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
>   Boolean& abortProcessing)

when I trying to call a webservice method from button click event using ajaxcall

```
$.ajax() {
    type: "POST",
    url: "RechargeService.asmx/ManageUser",
    //data: "{objUser: " + JSON.stringify(objUsers) + "}",
    data: "{Name:'" + Name + "',Address:'" + Address + "',City:'" + City + "',State:'" + State + "',Pincode:'" + Pincode + "',MobileNo:'" + MobileNo + "',Email:'" + Email + "',Password:'" + Password + "',Parameter:'" + Parameter + "',UserRole:'" + UserRole + "',UserStatus:'" + UserStatus + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data.d);
        if (data.Sucess) {
            $("#lblMsg").html('Registration done successfully');
            $("#txtEmail").val('');
            $("#txtPassword").val('');
            $("#txtMobileNo").val('');
            $("#txtConfirmPassword").val('');
            $('#myModal1').hide();
            alert("Your registration completed successfully");
        } else {
            alert("Already registered with this email id");
            $("#txtEmail").val("");
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText + " \n " + status + " \n " + error);

        alert("There was an error while processing. Please try again after some time.");
    }
}
```

Method

```
[WebMethod] 
Public string ManageUser()
{

}
```

This code works fine in local after hosting only i get the above error pls help me with this.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Brackets of jquery ajax are not valid. check [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: See its works fine in local i mean development environment brackets are fine i checked ... only after hosting i get the above error .. we need to do any change in hosting server

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by having **null** valued parameters in your WebMethod.

For example this:

```
public string GetDocument(int templateId, int? loginId = null)
```

...should be changed to this:

```
public string GetDocument(int templateId, int loginId)
```

Comment: And yet you provide no support for your claim. Why is that? Could you link a source?

Comment: @MMalke it's from personal experience. I always give answers to problems I personally had and solved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing brackets `()` in the ajax function that should be Like this

```
$.ajax({ 
     //Your Code...
});
```

Try this...

Comment: S i checked ... still facing same prob

Comment: i checked the same problem.. i added protocols in webconfig all the stuffs from net but still facing the error

Comment: @Muthu Check the valid handler mappings in web.config

Comment: @Muthu you can refer here : http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ConfiguringASPNETAJAX.aspx#httpHandlers

Comment: httphandlers and httpmodules are all fine.. i hosted in my local iis its works fine.. but while hosting in my domain server only i am getting this error..

Comment: Actually my problem is in my hosting server the iis application pool is in v2.0 but my .net framework is 4.0 the web method and ajax works only above .net framework 3.5 . so i changed the application pool to 4.0 now its works fine and thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Possible REASON 1:
did u add this in above the service class

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Possible Reason 2:
Data should have sigle quotes for patameter names as well

```
data:{'Name':'" + Name + "','Address':'" + Address + "'}
```